# Is the linear transformation $T(f(t))=t(f(t))$ from $P$ to $P$ an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-transformations

> Is the linear transformation $T(f(t))=t(f(t))$ from $P$ to $P$ an isomorphism?

I can say it is since:

1. The dimensions of domain and codomain are equal and
2. $\operatorname{ker}(T)$  is the function $f(x)=0$ (zero polynomial).

But the answer in my book states it's not an isomorphism because the function $f(x)=1$ is not in the image of $T$!

Comment: You should at least define what $P$ is. Is it the set of all polynomials over the base field? If it is, then its dimension is infinite, and (1) and (2) are sot sufficient to prove bijectivity.

Comment: What is P, what is t, what is f, why don't you explain what you ask about...? Now, when you mention "polynomial" things became clearer, yet this is no way to ask in college/university level.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(t)\ne 0$ then 
$$\deg(T(f(t))=\deg(f(t))+1$$
hence if $g(t)$ is a constant polynomial then it's degree is $0$ hence there's not a polynomial $f(t)$ such that $T(f(t))=g(t)$  so $T$ isn't bijective since it's not surjective.

Comment: Well put, dear friend!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $P$ is the set of all polynomials over a field $F$ in the variable $t$, the dimensions of the domain and codomain are equal but *infinite*, and so the two observations you've made aren't enough for the function to be an isomorphism. In addition to noting $T$ has trivial kernel, you'd need to show that $T$ is surjective, which in this case is false, since constant polynomials $f(t) = \alpha$ for $0 \neq \alpha \in F$ can't be written in the form $t g(t)$ for $g(t) \in P$.

Comment: P is the set of all polynomials.

Comment: f is a polynomial function

Comment: t is a variable

Comment: @user107849: Ok. Thanks. Then my answer applies.